# Saber quantas vezes aparece a letra 'a' em palavras salvas dentro de uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa que conta quantas vezes aparece a letra 'a' dentro de palavras escritas pelo utilizador, esse programa para quando se coloca um ponto final e faz a conta de quantas letras 'a' contém.
Porém quando faço isso em palavras dentro de uma lista é só contada as vezes que pressiono a letra 'a' sozinha, se ela está dentro de uma palavra a contagem não a reconhece.
o código que realizei foi esse

```py
contador_letras = []
 
 while True:
     letras_salvas = input('Digite uma letra: ')
     contador_letras.append(letras_salvas)
     if letras_salvas == '.':
         break
 
 contar = contador_letras.count('a')
 print(contar)
```

Comment: Não seria isso que o está tentando fazer: https://ideone.com/8V5vXp ou https://ideone.com/5VIren

Comment: Se for **somente** pra saber a quantidade (e não precisa guardar as palavras digitadas), nem precisa da lista, pode ser [assim](https://ideone.com/kGIRou). Se precisar guardar as palavras, aí vc usa a lista (algo [assim](https://ideone.com/NiMQdF) - veja que dá pra calcular no mesmo loop que lê os nomes). Claro que também poderia ser depois, aí poderia ser [assim](https://ideone.com/1Pisrz) - adaptando para o seu caso, bastaria vc fazer `contar = sum(s.count('a') for s in contador_letras)`

Answer (score -2):

Um dos motivos é que você está fazendo o append da palavra inteira e não realizando um split letra por letra, então quando você faz a pesquisa, ele vai procurar o valor todo como uma chave e só encontra quando você digitou apenas a letra.

Agreguei um código que resolve o problema e com os prints do passo a passo.

```
contador_letras = []
 
while True:
    letras_salvas = input('Digite uma letra: ')
    letras_separadas = list(letras_salvas)
    print(letras_separadas)
    contador_letras.append(letras_separadas)
    if letras_salvas == '.':
        break

contar = 0
for palavra in contador_letras:
    for i in palavra:
        if(i == "a"):
            print("Letra a encontrada")
            contar += 1
        
print(contar)
```